# Is it possible to format multiple chart data labels at once in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, label

I am trying to create a macro to edit data labels of multiple charts at the same time.

I currently have 9 charts on a single sheet that need to have the data labels set to format to “inside end”. Every time I change the data set I need to click on each individual chart and manually press “format to inside end”. Seeing as there are 200+ data sets, this becomes cumbersome. Is there a macro that can do this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what 'inside end' means, but you should be able to turn on the Macro Recorder, click through your usual steps, and then stop the Recorder.  You will have the code you need to make the changes you described.  Now, just iterate through each chart object and make the necessary changes.

```
Sub LoopThroughCharts()
'PURPOSE: Loop through every graph in the active workbook
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/The-Code-Vault

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
    cht.Activate
    
    'Do something with the chart...
  
  Next cht
Next sht

CurrentSheet.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```